# Bulk website query using text based browsers

Tags: bash, shell, curl, lynx, w3m

I want a text browser like *lynx*,*w3m* or *links* to perform a bulk query from a list of available links. The results will be filtered for a key word and should be added to the original list. 
An example, let the list be in `list.txt`:

```
"http://dict.cc//?s=Chemical"
"http://dict.cc//?s=Fenster"
```

I can extract the result if I only submit one link a time, e.g.

```
head -n 1 list.txt | xargs links -dump | sed -n '/NOUN/p'
tail -n 1 list.txt | xargs links -dump | sed -n '/NOUN/p'
```

works as expected, but **not**:

```
cat list.txt | xargs links -dump | sed -n '/NOUN/p'
```

or

```
for line in `cat list.txt`; do links -dump $line ; done
```

What am I doing wrong? Next step, the output should be appended to list in the correct line, so that *list.txt* will look like this after the operation:

```
"http://dict.cc//?s=Chemical" edit  NOUN   a chemical | chemicals       -
"http://dict.cc//?s=Fenster" NOUN   das Fenster | die Fenster    edit
```

Should be possible by combination or usage with other tools like *paste* etc. This does not work like above, what would be a better solution?:

```
for line in `cat list.txt`; do echo -n $line && links -dump $line; done
```

The example is just for demonstration, I will use other sites than *dict.cc*. Unfortunately no API/REST available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have twiddled with the commands until I found the bug. The problem lies in the double quotes of URLs given in *list.txt*. After removing, this works fine:

```
for line in `cat engl.txt`; do 
  echo -n $line && links -dump $line| sed -n '/NOUN/p' 
done
```

If one (has to) keep double quotes, using the entries in the file above as an command to *links* passed by *xargs* works (but not the command just above):

```
for line in `cat list.txt`; do 
  echo -n $line && echo $line | xargs links -dump | sed -n '/NOUN/p'
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` will pass more than one argument at once to the program, unless you limit the number of arguments: `xargs -n1 links -dump`. Maybe *links* only accepts one argument. If you only need the exact file in the URL and not any other linked documents, you may also use `curl`.

`for line in cat list.txt` splits at any whitespace. So it will not work if any line in `list.txt` contains spaces.

Try this to iterate over the list:

```
cat 'list.txt' | while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo -n $line && links -dump $line
done
```